# netplan doesn't support loopback routes eg: ip route add local default dev lo table 100

Tags: networking, server, netplan, ip, loop-device

I need to route everything with mark 1 to loopback address. With

```
ip rule add fwmark 1 table 100
```

and

```
ip route add local default dev lo table 100
```

It works fine. But I want to make it permanent with netplan. It never worked.
The original setup was:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ip rule show table 100
0:      from all fwmark 0x1 lookup 100
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ip route show table 100
local default dev lo scope host
```

the netplan yaml is:

```
        lo:
            match:
                name: lo
            routes:
                - table: 100
                  to: 0.0.0.0/0
                  via: 127.0.0.1
                  #
                  #scope: host
                  #on-link: true
            routing-policy:
                - to: 0.0.0.0/0
                  mark: 1
                  table: 100
```

after a netplan try command, the rule for fwmark 1 goes to table 100 works fine. but the route for everything in table 100 goes to loopback never appear. Table 100 always has been empty.

Comment: Had the same issue, but I came from Ubuntu 18.04 where that specific netplan yaml works. But no longer in Ubuntu 20.04. Found the same with manually adding the route via `ip route add local` works, just nothing with netplan.